# Pausing Records in Journey Over Weekend

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I'm looking to build a journey that sends a few emails only during the weekdays and then on Monday would send to anyone that was at that point over the weekend.
As an example, a record downloads a piece of content that gets captured in a data extension. 2 days after that download they receive an email. If they downloaded that piece of content on a Thursday or Friday, the email would be sent Saturday or Sunday. Instead it would be better to send it out on Monday.

I've tried to use some exclusion scripts on the emails themselves similar to below:

```
Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()),"ddd") == "Sat" OR Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()),"ddd") == "Sun"
```

This seems to prevent the send from happening, but then the record just goes onto the next step in the journey. I'm looking for a solution that would essentially pause the record over the weekend, then continue with the record on Monday.

Comment: Do you want to send it if the day falls on a public holidays like independence day or sth. similar? If not please include it in your question and i am also very interested how this can be done. (maybe with and without the development of a custom activity block for journey builder) ;)

Comment: Perhaps you can use the pause and resume API to handle this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_may_2020_dev_journey_pause.htm&type=5

Comment: Just to understand your advice @EazyE. You would create an external program, that pauses the Journey when there is an WeekEnd / Holiday. If it is a usual working day unpause it and make the journey resumes. Won't this make journey design and timelines much harder to understand? I mean it is a really common use case not to do certain things on localized calenders. Shouldn't salesforce deliver a new wait block for it where you can configure "dont progress on SAT/SUN" and then do also not progress inside the journey on dates that are inside the dataextension "United Kingdom Holidays" or similar?

Comment: Also wouldn't it be nicer if salesforce allowed better waiting blocks like "wait X working days" or "wait until next non working day". Where you then have to specify working days in dataextensions or predefined new content?

Comment: There are a lot of restrictions I'm facing with this. Can't send on weekends, not on public holidays for Brazil, and has to be at least 7 days after the action took place. I am able to accomplish any 2 of these things, but can't seem to knock out all 3 of them at the same time.